# How to check if any of column value is updated/deleted in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as.

```
_d = {'first_name':['Joe','Sha','Ram','Wes','David'],
      'last_name':['Doe','Jhu','Krishna','County','John'],
      'middle_name':['R.','M.','Q.','S.','I.']
    }

df_A = pd.DataFrame(_d)
```

[image]

Here, first I change middle name of a person who's last name is Doe as RA. as below.

```
df_A.loc[df_A['last_name']=='Doe','middle_name']='RA.'
```

So in pandas dataframe df_A an additional column is_changed is created and filled in with a value as Yes as below.

[image]

There are few more changes done as below

```
df_A.loc[df_A['first_name']=='David','last_name']='Curey'
```

```
df_A.loc[df_A['first_name']=='Ram','first_name']='Laxman'
```

Final expected output would be as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change (it seems you are doing it manually ?) then you also set the `is_changed` for e.g.

`df_A.loc[df_A['last_name']=='Doe','is_changed']='Yes'`

If not doing manually, how are you doing it? And also do you keep a copy of the original to compare?

Lets assume you do have a original copy `df_orig`. Then you could use [`pandas.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) to know whether a row changed or not like:

```
df.loc[df.compare(df_orig,keep_shape=True).any(axis=1), "is_changed"] = "Yes"
df["is_changed"] = df["is_changed"].fillna("")

print(df)

  first_name last_name middle_name is_changed
0        Joe       Doe         RA.        Yes
1        Sha       Jhu          M.           
2     Laxman   Krishna          Q.        Yes
3        Wes    County          S.           
4      David     Curey          I.        Yes
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works out .automatically is changed should be filled in. need to see how good it works on large amount of data.

Comment: I ran it on 400 rows and 35 columns dataset. it says as: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

Comment: df_changed = pd.DataFrame(_df.compare(_df_bkp,keep_shape=True).any(axis=1))
df_changed.columns=['is_changed']
pd.concat([_df,df_changed],axis=1)

Comment: *This is usually the result of calling frame.insert many times, which has poor performance.* is actually you would like to avoid. As it suggested, you need to concat rather than using insert multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample I tried.

```
import pandas as pd

_d = {
    "first_name": ["Joe", "Sha", "Ram", "Wes", "David"],
    "last_name": ["Doe", "Jhu", "Krishna", "County", "John"],
    "middle_name": ["R.", "M.", "Q.", "S.", "I."],
}

df_A = pd.DataFrame(_d)
df_B = df_A.copy()

df_A.loc[df_A["last_name"] == "Doe", "middle_name"] = "RA."
df_A.loc[df_A["first_name"] == "David", "last_name"] = "Curey"
df_A.loc[df_A["first_name"] == "Ram", "first_name"] = "Laxman"

df_A["is_changed"] = (
    df_A[df_B.columns]
    .ne(df_B)
    .apply(lambda x: any(x), axis=1)
    .replace({True: "Yes", False: ""})
)
print(df_A)
```